# Does C++ support multi-type variables?

Tags: c++

Does C++ support compound data types? In the below Python example, var is a compound data type.

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        print 'a'

class B(object):
    def foo(self):
        print 'b'

var = None    
if something:
    var = A()
else:
    var = B()

var.foo()
```

Is there a way to declare var in C++? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How have that worked, or not worked? Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There's `auto` which is **similar** but not exactly the same as `var` in python. Besides that, C++ is a statically typed language whereas Python is dynamically typed, so no direct analog exists.

Comment: Also, ***why*** are you asking? What is the *actual* problem you have? This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where you ask for help fixing a solution to an for us unknown problem. Perhaps there are better solutions for the original problem?

Comment: I tested nothing since from my quick search is not possible.
But it's why I ask here.

But auto is on compile time or runtime? Since my conditional statement will be executed at runtime, SO I doubt auto will suits.

Comment: Define an abstract base class `Base` with `foo` method, derive `A` and `B` classes from it. Declare `Base *var`. Depending on your condition write either `var = new A()` or `var = new B()`.

Comment: You have a problem. The problem is *not* "how do I do this", but the *reason* you want to do this. Why do you want to do dynamic typing in C++? Are you just attempting to do a straight port of a Python program (not really possible)? Are you just curious? Is there some other problem you need to solve, and you think dynamic typing is the best solution?

Comment: Thanks @IvanGritsenko I wasafraidr of this (I mean is a lot of code for this) but if it's the only way to go I will do it ! Thanks :)

Comment: FYI, dyno does the whole "anything you can foo" thing pretty well for C++ without reflection: https://github.com/ldionne/dyno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ is a strongly typed language, so as written this code can't be converted into C++.

You can do something similar by using an interface / abstract base class:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class A : public Foo
{
public:
    virtual void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "a";
    }
};

class B : public Foo
{
public:
    virtual void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "b";
    }
};

int main(int arg, char** argv)
{
    Foo* foo = nullptr;
    if(...)
    {
        foo = new A();
    }
    else
    {
        foo = new B();
    }

    foo->foo();
    delete foo;
}
```

(Note that it is much better to use smart pointers here instead of explicitly calling `new` and `delete`, but I wanted to keep the code simple.)

Comment: Using smart pointers *is* simpler!

Comment: Even if variant is very conviniant, this method will work in all cpp version then thanks for it !

Comment: Downvoted because this unnecessarily requires dynamic allocation and because `new`/`delete` should never be used in modern C++. As aschepler said, smart pointers are simpler.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) or `boost::variant`:

```
using AorB = std::variant<A, B>;
```

Example:

```
AorB var;
if(something) var = A{};
else var = B{};
```

Calling `foo`:

```
std::visit([](auto& x){ x.foo(); }, var);
```

Comment: Thanks you Will go for this way !
EDIT:
Sadly only c++ 17, wich is not available for my project. But I'm fine to know it's will possible in future for me.

Comment: Using this way, you can't call `var.foo();` though, which is why polymorphism is usually a better solution.  You could improve this answer by demonstrating how to call `foo` using a visitor.

Comment: @graphos: you can use `boost::variant` instead.

Comment: Can't use 3rd party library too, should said it before.
But anyway I will go to the @Andy solution

Comment: @graphos: then write a `variant` class for your company and become a rockstar! :P